# What 2nd group with data (for example: Index::index on home) in ZendDevelopersTools Toolbar?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am not sure that question name is correct. Edit it please or suggest something better if it is not enought good.

ZendDeveloperTools Toolbar looks like:

[image]

What the data in 2nd group means? This data:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Google doesn't want provide any help: [Google — What data presented in zenddevelopertools](https://www.google.ru/search?q=What%20data%20presented%20in%20zenddevelopertools)

Thats why I am asking here.

I thought this block represents something like: `Controller::Action on Module`, but zf2 doesn't have module `home`, it has `Application`. And yes, `Application` module has `IndexController` controller and `index` action in it. But why `home`? Same for `zfcuser`. I have `zfcuser` module in my project — ok. But controller name is `UserController`, not `zfcuser`.

Can you explain me what data is represented in this block?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that's the name of the currently matched route.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly each word means? `?::? on ?`

Comment: `Controller`::`Action` on `RouteName`

Comment: Aaaah. Now I get it. Now I understand why `home` is here, but not `Application`. Thank you very much.